# Sleuth Brave headers are not compatible with JMS spec

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-jms, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Sleuth in Spring Integration project to pass along tracing headers across JMS messages. IBM MQ is used for Queue Manager. This configuration is working all fine functionally. However, all the Brave header `X-B3-*` are not compatible with JMS spec? As IBM MQ client lib throws a warning about this -

**Warning Message:** 
`JMSCC0049: The property name 'X-B3-Sampled' is not a valid Java(tm) identifier.`

**JMS Payload:** 
`2018-03-13 11:54:42.919  INFO [domain-batch,d5a9e59728d0846a,954264c0e98a448b,false] 141252 --- [ask-scheduler-2] c.l.p.module.biz.BackendServiceClient    : Message: GenericMessage [payload=2018-03-13T11:54:42.856, headers={JMS_IBM_Character_Set=UTF-8, jms_destination=queue:///DEV.QUEUE.1, JMS_IBM_Encoding=273, jms_timestamp=1520956482869, JMS_IBM_PutApplType=28, spanId=9a20699cdc50f7e9, JMS_IBM_Format=MQSTR   , JMSXDeliveryCount=1, X-B3-Sampled=0, JMS_IBM_PutTime=15544287, X-B3-TraceId=d5a9e59728d0846a, id=d40cfbec-5dce-a8cd-0d96-da0e3d761459, jms_messageId=ID:414d5120514d3120202020202020202035a3a35aae92fa20, JMS_IBM_MsgType=8, JMSXUserID=app         , X-B3-ParentSpanId=385f47b14a627448, priority=4, JMSXAppID=BackendServiceApplication   , spanTraceId=d5a9e59728d0846a, spanParentSpanId=385f47b14a627448, nativeHeaders={spanTraceId=[d5a9e59728d0846a], spanId=[9a20699cdc50f7e9], spanParentSpanId=[385f47b14a627448], spanSampled=[0]}, jms_redelivered=false, JMS_IBM_PutDate=20180313, X-B3-SpanId=9a20699cdc50f7e9, spanSampled=0}]`

Is there an option in sleuth to change the header naming convention for JMS? Similar to the [baggage naming convention](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/single/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_prefixed_fields) ? Hopefully I am not missing something from the documentation.

**EDIT:**
Add the following log level config to suppress the warning exception

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper: ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those warnings can be ignored. We're setting both the `X-B3-Sampled` and the `spanSampled` headers (check this out https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/master/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/messaging/MessageHeaderPropagation.java). The first ones are not compatible the second ones are JMS compatible

Comment: Thats correct, everything works as expected, but will need to find a way to suppress the warning.

Comment: Adding ERROR log level to org.springframework.integration.jms.DefaultJmsHeaderMapper class suppress the warning statements

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/issues/584 is the longer topic in brave. JMS is unfortunate.

Luckily, we've recently changed the format of the successor to B3 "Trace Context" which no longer uses hyphens so won't make JMS sad. https://github.com/w3c/distributed-tracing/tree/master/trace_context Note: this is not an implementation version of the spec yet, but anyway you can follow it.